# ¿Actualizar Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Tengo una galería que se divide en dos secciones, la cual uso dos `Tab` para dividirla, uso `ViewPager`. He aquí mi código del la clase `Pager` y por ende uso `Fragments`, tengo impliementados varios métodos eliminar imagen tomar/capturar fotos/imágenes, el detalle está en que cuando tomo/capturo una imagen para añadirla en la galería (en cualquiera de las dos secciones), no encuentro como refrescar o actualizar o recargar el `Fragment` de la seccion que añadí la foto:

```
  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "Sec 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "Sev 2");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de responder una pregunta similar lo que necesitas es obtener las intancias de los fragments dentro de tu viewpager para luego actualizarlos esta es una forma tambien puedes enviar un broadcast a cada fragment y que cada fragment actualize la informacion al recibirlo te mostrare como hacerlo obteniendo las instancias.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); // Esto es para que se retenga la informacion de los dos fragment


/**
*
* Aqui obtienes las dos secciones
*
**/
Tab1 seccion1_frag;
Tab2 seccion2_frag;

if(adapter.getItem(0)!=null) {
  seccion1_frag = (Tab1) adapter.getItem(0);
}

if(adapter.getItem(1)!=null) {
  seccion2_frag = (Tab2) adapter.getItem(1);
}
```

Ahora ya tienes las intancias de cada fragment o de cada seccion por decirlo asi ahora yo lo que te recomiendo es que a cada fragment le crees una funcion llamada "actualizar" y listo despues las llamas.

```
seccion1_frag.actualizar(); // dentro de la funcion actualizas lo que necesitas
seccion2_frag.actualizar();
```

puedes agregarle una validación de nulo a los fragment para evitar problemas nunca esta de mas.